# With Rails 4.2 and lograge, how do I enable date/times before each logged line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, logging, ruby-on-rails-4

I use the gem “Lograge” 0.3.6, and Rails 4.2.  I have this configured in my config/environments/development.rb file

```
  config.lograge.enabled = true
  config.lograge.formatter = CustomLogstash.new
```

However, I notice the output in my log/development.log file doesn’t contain date/times in front of each line.  How do I configure lograge (or maybe just my Rails logger?) to prefix each line in that file with a date and time?

Answer (score 1):

As per the [document](https://github.com/roidrage/lograge), the lograge gem provides below log formatters.

```
Lograge::Formatters::Lines.new  # need to install "lines" gem
Lograge::Formatters::Cee.new
Lograge::Formatters::Graylog2.new
Lograge::Formatters::KeyValue.new  # default lograge format
Lograge::Formatters::Json.new
Lograge::Formatters::Logstash.new  # need to install "logstash-event" gem 
Lograge::Formatters::LTSV.new
Lograge::Formatters::Raw.new       # Returns a ruby hash object
```

By default the [lograge](https://github.com/roidrage/lograge) gem uses `Lograge::Formatters::KeyValue.new` format for log.

You can customize this and make it universal by using your `CustomLogStash` class with some changes.

```
class CustomLogStash < Lograge::Formatters::KeyValue
  def call(data)
    # I'm using timestamp key here, you can choose whatever you want.
    data_hash = { timestamp: Time.now.utc.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3N")}.merge!(data)
    super(data_hash)
  end
end
```

Same way you can use any `Lograge::Formatters` class and apply the custom  format to the log.

Now add below code to your `config/initializers/lograge.rb` file.

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.lograge.enabled = true
  config.lograge.formatter = CustomLogStash.new
end
```

Now restart your server and load a page in your browser. You will see the logs something like below:

```
timestamp=2021-11-21T17:14:10.726 method=GET path=/categories format=html controller=categories action=index status=200 duration=259.11 view=244.91 db=2.60
```

**EDITED**

If you are looking for logs something like
[image]

then you don't need any gem for this. You can achieve this by adding below lines to your preferred environment development/production/test

```
config.log_level = :debug
config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
```

If you want to apply this across all environments then add above lines to the `config/application.rb` file.

Comment: I confirm what you report above -- that the requests for controller methods are prefixed with that timestamp.  This is really good.  I notice that the other output in my log/development.log file, e.g. the loading of objects from the db are not prefixed with the timestamp (they appear as "Product Load (2.3ms)  SELECT  `products`.* …").  Any way to adjust the above to make the timestamp prefix universal?

Comment: @Dave - do you want something like this https://ibb.co/MyzLbJP

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the following in config if it helps.

```
config.lograge.formatter = ->(data) { data.reverse_merge({time: Time.now}) }# data is a ruby hash.
```

It will give you output like following

```
{:time=>2021-11-16 12:26:24.65362 +0000, :method=>"GET", :path=>"/", :format=>:html, :controller=>"Controller", :action=>"index", :status=>200, :duration=>393.41, :view=>85.55, :db=>1.38}
```

Comment: Gave this a go but no dice.  After restarting my server, still no dates prepended in my log/development.log file.

Comment: Do you have different lograge config for each environment?

Comment: The configuration is the same but there are three separate files -- config/environments/development.rb, config/environments/staging.rb, and config/environments/production.rb.

Comment: Which custom logger formatter are you using in your config? Like you mentioned in your example above config.lograge.formatter = CustomLogstash.new

Comment: Also is it possible if you could share how does your development config looks like?

Comment: I removed all my "config.lograge" directives and included only the line you had above, but after restarting my server and running my app, I don't see any timestamps prepended to the log/development.log file.

Comment: You don't need to remove all "config.lograge" directives. At-least you need the following in you config to enable the lograge logger. 
 config.lograge.enabled = true
if you just adding above then you should be able to add timestamp by adding the following config
  config.lograge.enabled = true
  # add time to lograge
  config.lograge.custom_options = lambda do |event|
    { time: Time.now }
  end
This won't prefix the timestamp, However it will add the timestamp into the log entry

Comment: Also if you wish to continue with the custom logger formatter. Then try with the simple JSON ( Lograge::Formatters::Json) formatter given on lograge Github page
https://github.com/roidrage/lograge
So your development config will look something like following
  config.lograge.enabled = true
  config.lograge.formatter = Lograge::Formatters::Json.new
  config.lograge.formatter = ->(data) { data.reverse_merge({time: Time.now}) }

Comment: Tried the solution with the "Time.now" but still nothing in my log/development.log file is prefixed with a date or time.

Answer (score 0):

As per [official documentation](https://github.com/roidrage/lograge) for `lograge`, you can make use of `custom_options`

**EDIT 1** : custom_options using `time: Time.now` or  `time:event.time`

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.lograge.enabled = true
  config.lograge.formatter = Lograge::Formatters::Logstash.new

  # add time to lograge
  config.lograge.custom_options = lambda do |event|
    { time: Time.now } #or use time:event.time 
  end
end
```

> Note: When using the logstash output, you need to add the additional gem logstash-event. You can simply add it to your Gemfile like this

```
      gem "logstash-event"
```

**EDIT 2:** Update based on comments custom_options using **`:time => event.time`**

```
#config/environments/production.rb
MyApp::Application.configure do
  config.lograge.enabled = true

  # add time to lograge
  config.lograge.custom_options = lambda do |event|
    {:time => event.time}
  end
end
```

**OR** the below custom options which was a fix in [lograge issue to ensure both](https://github.com/roidrage/lograge/issues/70)  date and time logged using **`time: event.time.to_s(:db)`**

```
config.lograge.custom_options = lambda do |event|
      unwanted_keys = %w[format action controller utf8]
      params = event.payload[:params].reject { |key,_| unwanted_keys.include? key }
      {time: event.time.to_s(:db), user: event.payload[:user], params: params}
    end
```

**ALTERNATIVELY** you can use this [Custom logger](https://gist.github.com/seanlinsley/4670262)

```
# Define a setter to pass in a custom log formatter

class ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger

  def formatter=(formatter)

    @log.formatter = formatter

  end

end



# Defines a custom log format (time, severity, message, PID, backtrace)... all with color!

class Formatter

  SEVERITY_TO_TAG   = {'DEBUG'=>'meh', 'INFO'=>'fyi', 'WARN'=>'hmm', 'ERROR'=>'wtf', 'FATAL'=>'omg', 'UNKNOWN'=>'???'}

  SEVERITY_TO_COLOR = {'DEBUG'=>'37',  'INFO'=>'32',  'WARN'=>'33',  'ERROR'=>'31',  'FATAL'=>'31',  'UNKNOWN'=>'37'}

  HUMOR_FOR_ENV     = {development: true, test: true, production: false}

  DEPTH_FOR_ENV     = {development: 3,    test: 3,    production: 1}

  EXCLUSION_REGEX   = /log|active_support|active_record/



  def humorous?

    return @is_humorous if defined? @is_humorous

    @is_humorous = HUMOR_FOR_ENV[ Rails.env.to_sym ]

  end



  def depth

    @depth ||= DEPTH_FOR_ENV[ Rails.env.to_sym ]

  end



  def call(severity, time, progname, msg)

    t     = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.") << time.usec.to_s[0..2].rjust(3)

    color = SEVERITY_TO_COLOR[severity]

    sev   = humorous? ? "%-3s" % SEVERITY_TO_TAG[severity] # pad to at least 3 characters

                      : "%-5s" % severity                  # pad to at least 5 characters



    # 2013-05-01 19:16:00.785 [omg] oh noes! (pid:30976) (admin/user.rb:45:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>') <- `call' <- `content_for' <- `block (2 levels) in row' <- `block in build_tag'

    "\033[0;37m#{t}\033[0m [\033[#{color}m#{sev}\033[0m] #{msg.strip} (pid:#{$$}) #{whodunit}\033[0m\n"

  end



  def whodunit

    latest, *others = caller.select{ |a| a !~ EXCLUSION_REGEX }[0, depth]

    latest = latest[/(lib|app)\/(.*)/,-1] || latest

    string = ""

    string << "\033[36m(#{latest})"

    string << "\033[35m <- " + others.map{ |s| s[/`.*/] }.join(' <- ') if others.any?

    string

  end



end



Rails.logger.formatter = Formatter.new
```

For Rails 4.2 don’t forget to add ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging to be able to call custom logger like a default rails logger

> ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging is used to wrap any standard logger instance to add "tags" to a log statement. A "tag" in this case usually describes a subdomain, and is used by the default Rails.logger to allow you to tag log statements with subdomains, request ids, etc. in your multi-user, multi-instance production applications.

```
include 
ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging::Formatter
```

to the `Formatter` class.

Comment: Unfortunately neither produces prefixed time entries in the log/development.log file.

Comment: @Dave do check with new updated code for `custom_options `

Comment: When you say "include 
ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging::Formatter to the Formatter class", what is that?  I don't have a class named Formatter in my project, at least not one that I've created.

Comment: It’s ideally required when you create custom logger, I have added the custom logger which seems to have been missed out in my previous edit

Comment: The custom logger you added, class ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger, in what directory should that be placed?

Comment: @Dave the custom logger is the `class Formatter`, `ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger` is the setter to the custom logger

Comment: @Dave custom loggers are always placed in `lib/` or `config/initializers `

Comment: To refer the custom logger, `class Formatter` in your config file you must change the line 2 as mentioned in your question to `config.lograge.formatter =Formatter.new` in the development.rb file

Comment: As mentioned earlier for Rails4.2, don’t forget to rewrite `class Formatter` in custom logger file to `class Formatter< ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging::Formatter `

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste contents of **CustomLogstash** class? From docs, this class should respond to **call** method and return **Hash**.

This works for me:

```rb
class CustomLogstash
  def call(data)
    { time: Time.now, controller: data[:controller] } # this can be anything as long it is Hash, eg. data.merge(time: Time.now)

  end
end
```

Sample output from above:

```
{:time=>"2021-11-18T20:31:41.486+01:00", :controller=>"calendar_events"}
```

Comment: Are you saying I should create this class?  I don't have a class named this anywhere in my project.

Comment: I am referring to code you have pasted so I was assuming that you already have this class. If not, create it and ensure it is loaded before `config.lograge.formatter = CustomLogstash.new` call.

Comment: Gotcha.  So including that line did seem to add lines into the log/development.log file when a controller method was called and they were prepended with a timestamp, e.g. '{:time=>"2021-11-21T03:46:53.525+00:00", :controller=>"api/products"}'.  Any way to make this universal?  To add the timestamp to everything (e.g. the SQL queries that are recorded)